# Why does list within list get overwritten?

Tags: python, list, pass-by-reference

In the following code, I don't get the result that I expect.

For a `starting_number`, `current_result` gets calculated. The value of it is appended to `every_result` - at least that's what I would expect. But, the value gets overwritten in the next iteration. What's happening? Is a reference being passed instead of the value? Why?

```
def get_integers(current, integers=[]):
    # Return the list of integers
    # e.g. for current = 2, return [2, 1, 0]
    if current == -1:
        return integers
    else:
        integers.append(current)
        return get_integers(current - 1, integers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    starting_numbers = [1, 2]
    every_result = []
    for starting_number in starting_numbers:
        current_result = get_integers(starting_number)
        every_result.append(current_result)

    print(every_result)
```

```
# Expected output:
# [[1, 0], [2, 1, 0]]

# Actual output:
# [[1, 0, 2, 1, 0], [1, 0, 2, 1, 0]]
```

If I modify `get_integers` like below, I get the expected output.

```
def get_integers(current):
    return list(range(current + 1))
```

Comment: Congratlations. You have fallen into the [mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) trap.

Comment: ah this now makes sense! I was going mad.